# Compare cells in table and add CSS class to its <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a table with so many rows. it's structure is like this code

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Name</td>
         <td>Criteria</td>
         <td>Grade</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Nick</td>
         <td>5</td>
         <td>5.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>David</td>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>11.5</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: jquery table]

I want if the grade was bigger than criteria, a CSS class named `good` be assigned to the `<tr>` otherwise the class name be `bad` (based on one `<th>` the `<tr>`  will have a class name).
  The runtime result will be like this (pay attention to line 11 and 19):

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Name</td>
         <td>Criteria</td>
         <td>Grade</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="good">
         <td>Nick</td>
         <td>5</td>
         <td>5.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="bad">
         <td>David</td>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>2.5</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that my intention is to highlight good bad result rows with CSS.

Comment: @Blender no clue. i'm new to jquery

Comment: @DavidPeterson, new to something? then read the documentation, do some Googling, and THEN if you get stuck at something we're all happy to help.

Comment: @Adnan I've done these works. i will remember your advice. Thank you man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('tbody tr').each(
    function(){
        var that = $(this),
            criteria = parseInt(that.find('td:eq(1)').text(),10),
            grade = parseInt(that.find('td:eq(2)').text(),10),
            trClass = grade > criteria ? 'good' : 'notGood';
        that.addClass(trClass);
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qtY5f/).

Note the `tbody` in the selector, to prevent this applying to the first row, I moved that row into a `thead` element, since it *seems* to be a header for the table.

Note that, in the above, the `each()` is, strictly speaking, unnecessary as `addClass()` could be used with a function:

```
$('tbody tr').addClass(function() {
    var that = $(this),
        criteria = parseInt(that.find('td:eq(1)').text(), 10),
        grade = parseInt(that.find('td:eq(2)').text(), 10);
        return grade > criteria ? 'good' : 'notGood';
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qtY5f/1/).

---

**Edited** to address the fact that I'd used `parseInt()`, instead of `parseFloat()` to handle the conversion of text to number:

```
$('tbody tr').addClass(function() {
    var that = $(this),
        criteria = parseFloat(that.find('td:eq(1)').text()),
        grade = parseFloat(that.find('td:eq(2)').text());
        return grade > criteria ? 'good' : 'notGood';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qtY5f/2/).

Comment: Question, did you store `$(this)` to preserve it in this scope or just not repeat calling `$` on `this`?

Comment: Just to avoid repeatedly recreating the jQuery `$(this)` object. If It had been used only once then I wouldn't have bothered, but twice is needless.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Lately I've been very confused about scopes (especially after getting into jQuery plugin patterns) so whenever I see someone doing something with `this` I panic and I have to ask.